# Terraform virtual wan azurerm_vpn_gateway_connection

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

Looking to create dynamic Azure vwan vpn site connections. I am using this map to define the sites and links. I would like to be able to add and remove sites and links as my requirements change.

```
virtual_wan_vpn_sites = {
  vwan_site_dc = {
    name = "site-shr-infra-dc"
    location_map_key   = "primary"
    resource_group_key = "rg_vwan"
    vwan_key = "vwan"
    device_vendor = "Fortigate"
    device_model = "FGT60F"
    links = {
      link_1 = {
        name = "link-shr-infra-dc-1"
        bgp_asn = "64512"
        public_ip_address = "1.1.1.1"
        bgp_peering_ip = "10.10.100.1"
      }
      link_2 = {
        name = "link-shr-infra-dc-2"
        bgp_asn = "64513"
        public_ip_address = "2.2.2.2"
        bgp_peering_ip = "10.10.100.100"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this code to create the sites, links, and connections.

```
# Create vpn site(s)
module "virtualWanVpnSites" {
  source = "../../modules/networking/virtual_wan_vpn_site"
  for_each = var.virtual_wan_vpn_sites

  name                    = each.value.name
  location                = var.location_map[each.value.location_map_key]
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group[each.value.resource_group_key].name
  virtual_wan_id          = module.virtualWan[each.value.vwan_key].virtual_wan_id
  vwan_key                = each.value.vwan_key
  vwan_sites              = each.value.links
  device_vendor           = each.value.device_vendor
  device_model            = each.value.device_model
  vpn_gateways            = values(module.virtualHubVpn)[*].virtual_hub_vpn_gateway_id
  tags                    = merge(lookup(each.value, "tags", {}), local.tags)

../../modules/networking/virtual_wan_vpn_site

# Virtual Wan vpn site
resource "azurerm_vpn_site" "vwan_vpn_site" {
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_wan_id      = var.virtual_wan_id
  device_vendor       = var.device_vendor
  device_model        = var.device_model
  tags                = local.tags

  dynamic "link" {
    for_each = try(var.vwan_sites, {})
    content {
      name          = link.value.name
      ip_address    = link.value.public_ip_address
      bgp {
        asn               = link.value.bgp_asn
        peering_address   = link.value.bgp_peering_ip
      }
    }
  }
}

# vhub vpn gateway connection
resource "azurerm_vpn_gateway_connection" "vhub_vpn_gateway_connection" {
  for_each = toset(var.vpn_gateways)

  name               = "example"
  vpn_gateway_id     = each.key
  remote_vpn_site_id = azurerm_vpn_site.vwan_vpn_site.id

  *dynamic "vpn_link" {
    for_each = try(azurerm_vpn_site.vwan_vpn_site.link, [])
    content {
      name              = vpn_link.value.name
      vpn_site_link_id  = vpn_link.value.id
      bgp_enabled       = true
    }
  }*
}
```

The vwan site and links get created successfully, however, the link connections error out with this:

```
Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   with module.virtualWanVpnSites["vwan_site_dc"].azurerm_vpn_gateway_connection.vhub_vpn_gateway_connection["/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/vpnGateways/vpn-shr-infra-usce"],
│   on ../../modules/networking/virtual_wan_vpn_site/module.tf line 25, in resource "azurerm_vpn_gateway_connection" "vhub_vpn_gateway_connection":
│   25: resource "azurerm_vpn_gateway_connection" "vhub_vpn_gateway_connection" {
│ 
│ The argument "vpn_link.1.vpn_site_link_id" is required, but no definition
│ was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   with module.virtualWanVpnSites["vwan_site_dc"].azurerm_vpn_gateway_connection.vhub_vpn_gateway_connection["/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/vpnGateways/vpn-shr-infra-use2"],
│   on ../../modules/networking/virtual_wan_vpn_site/module.tf line 25, in resource "azurerm_vpn_gateway_connection" "vhub_vpn_gateway_connection":
│   25: resource "azurerm_vpn_gateway_connection" "vhub_vpn_gateway_connection" {
│ 
│ The argument "vpn_link.1.vpn_site_link_id" is required, but no definition
│ was found.
```

It appears that the resource **azurerm_vpn_gateway_connection** wants the **vpn_site_link_id** like this **vpn_site_link_id = azurerm_vpn_site.example.*link[0]*.id**.

> https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/vpn_gateway_connection

I can see the links in the state file like this:

```
      "module": "module.virtualWanVpnSites[\"vwan_site_dc\"]",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "azurerm_vpn_site",
      "name": "vwan_vpn_site",
      "provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm\"]",
      "instances": [
        {
          "schema_version": 0,
          "attributes": {
            "address_cidrs": [],
            "device_model": "FGT60F",
            "device_vendor": "Fortigate",
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/vpnSites/site-shr-infra-dc",
            "link": [
              {
                "bgp": [
                  {
                    "asn": 64512,
                    "peering_address": "10.10.100.1"
                  }
                ],
                "fqdn": "",
                "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/vpnSites/site-shr-infra-dc/vpnSiteLinks/link-shr-infra-dc-1",
                "ip_address": "1.1.1.1",
                "name": "link-shr-infra-dc-1",
                "provider_name": "",
                "speed_in_mbps": 0
              },
              {
                "bgp": [
                  {
                    "asn": 64513,
                    "peering_address": "10.10.100.100"
                  }
                ],
                "fqdn": "",
                "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/vpnSites/site-shr-infra-dc/vpnSiteLinks/link-shr-infra-dc-2",
                "ip_address": "2.2.2.2",
                "name": "link-shr-infra-dc-2",
                "provider_name": "",
                "speed_in_mbps": 0
              }
            ],
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check  this [terraform-azurerm-virtual-wan · GitHub](https://github.com/claranet/terraform-azurerm-virtual-wan/blob/main/examples/vpn/modules.tf)

Initially , check if the version is the issue and see with v2.78.0 version of the Terraform Provider.

- Try also  setting `address_cidrs` to create an address space

I have used `address_cidrs       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]` for azurerm_vpn_site
And address_prefix      = "10.0.0.0/24" in azurerm_virtual_hub.

```
vpn_sites = [
    {
      name = "site1"
      links = [
        {
          name       = "site1-primary-endpoint"
          ip_address = "20.20.20.20"
          bgp = [
            {
              asn             = 65530
              peering_address = "169.254.21.2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name       = "site1-secondary-endpoint"
          ip_address = "21.21.21.21"
          bgp = [
            {
              asn             = 65530
              peering_address = "169.254.22.2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

As you said  vpn_link is expected in the format vpn_site_link_id  = `vpn_link.value[0].id`

[image]

Please also check the **Reference** : [Terraform for-each with list of objects - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64919126/terraform-for-each-with-list-of-objects)