# Create a dynamic terraform resource

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

All the examples of terraform for_each and dynamic that I can find are nested within a resource. I want to create a dynamic list of resources themselves out of a 'set' input variable.

For example, the `azurerm_mssql_firewall_rule` is a descrete resource, so in order to have many firewall rules, I'd need something like

Parent Module:

```
module "AzureSqlServer" {
    allowedIPs = local.azureSqlAllowedIPs
}

variable "azureSQLAllowedIPs" {
    type = map(object({
        name = string
        ipAddress = string
    }))
}
```

Child module:

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_firewall_rule" "azureSQLFirewall"{
    for_each var.azureSQLAllowedIPs
    name             = each.value["name"]
    server_id        = azurerm_mssql_server.azureSqlServer.id
    start_ip_address = each.value["ipAddress"]
    end_ip_address   = each.value["ipAddress"]
}
```

Is there some way to do `dynamic` outside the block?

Comment: "dynamic outside the block" - can you please clarify what do you mean by that? Do you have any example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: hello @NitrusCS, are you trying to add for_each in `sql_server` module instead of the `azurerm_mssql_firewall_rule `resource block present inside the Module?

Comment: I want to pass in multiple IP addresses and create a ```azurerm_mssql_firewall_rule``` for each value. Unlike the ```aws_security_group``` resource where the ```ingress1``` property is already a list, Azure SQL firewall rules are a distinct resource for each IP range you want to allow in.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was close. Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594506/how-to-for-each-through-a-listobjects-in-terraform-0-12) I was able to figure it out:

```
variable "azureSQLAllowedIPs" {
    type = map(object({
        name = string
        ipAddress = string
    }))
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_firewall_rule" "azureSQLFirewall" {
    for_each = var.azureSQLAllowedIPs
    name             = each.value.name
    server_id        = azurerm_mssql_server.sql_server.id
    start_ip_address = each.value.ipAddress
    end_ip_address   = each.value.ipAddress
}
```

(missing a "=" after the `for_each` and reference the map element by dot notation instead of string reference.