# Terraform for_each on custom registry

Tags: module, terraform

We have a custom VPC registry built within our organization. The objective is to enable user of registry to be able to create VPC, create multiple public and private subnets for multiple availability zones within VPC.

I have a for_each variable set at

```
variable az_sub {list(object(
az = string,
public_cidr_block = list,
private_cidr_block =list
))}
```

Variable has a value of

```
[{az='us-east-1a",
 public_cidr_block =[list of cidr],
 private_cidr_block= [list of cidr]
 },
 az='us-east-1b",
 public_cidr_block =[list of cidr],
 private_cidr_block= [list of cidr} ]
```

When I set for_each on this within registry,

```
module "az"{
source="./modules/az"
vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
for_each = toset(keys({for i,v in var.az_sub: i => v}))
availability_zone = var.az_sub[each.value]["az"]
public_cidr_block = var.az_sub[each.value]["public_cidr_block"]
private_cidr_block  =var.az_sub[each.value]["private_cidr_block"]
}
```

I get unsupported attribute error on terraform/modules/modReg/output.tf in output public_subnet_ids
**module.az is object with 2 attributes**

output.tf has the outputs defined.
The az variables.tf has all three variables defined.
Also Note, if I replace for_each with below,  do not get errors, but objects are successfully created on aws

```
availability_zone="us-east-1a"
public_cidr_block = ["10.97.224.0/22"]
private_cidr_block  =["10.97.228.0/22"]
```

So doubt its issue with az module

Note, if I use only 1 az zone on the variable value for list(object) I the error changes to
module.az is object with 1 attribute "us-east-1"

Comment: What is the full code of the resource where you use `for_each = var.az_subnet`?

Comment: Note as mentioned, the process works in absence of for_each, when actual values are given. Its basic terraform registry configuration really.

Output public_subnet_ids would give list of subnet_ids for the subnets that have been created on aws, output.tf is basic config of terraform. 

The above has the full **error message** already.

What other details are you looking for?

Comment: "The full error message" typically means a verbatim copy of exactly what Terraform printed into your terminal, in full and without any summarization on your part, since it isn't clear yet which parts of the output are important to diagnostic the problem and which are not. (If you do need to redact certain parts for security reasons then that's okay, but be very clear about what you are omitting and omit as little as possible.)

Answer (score 0):

```
output "private_subnet_ids" {
  description = "List of private subnet IDs"
  value       = values(module.az).*.private_subnet_ids
}
```

For anyone having same issue, this resolved the problem. I had used list(object and not map(object. If map(object was used, then output.tf would need to have map values.

If you use for_each to send values to the module, the outputs would need to be defined as shown above.