# JSON iteration on Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Trying to create a simple VPC and a Subnet by iterating over a JSON file to Terraform code.

#### I already figured most of it out.. the only variable missing is the cidr_block for my subnet, How do i approach this?

```
{
    "vpc1" : {
    "name": "first-vpc",
    "cidr": "192.168.0.0/16",
    "subnets" :[
    {"name":"subnet-one", "cidr": "192.168.1.0/24"}, {"name":"subnet-two", "cidr":
    "192.168.4.0/24"}
    ]
    },
    "vpc2" : {
    "name": "second-vpc",
    "cidr": "172.16.0.0/16",
    "subnets" :[
    {"name":"subnet-three", "cidr": "172.16.1.0/24"}, {"name":"subnet-four", "cidr":
    "172.16.7.0/24"}
    ]
    }
}
```

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  for_each = { for index, vm in local.json : vm.name => vm }

  cidr_block = each.value.cidr

  tags = {
    Name = each.value.name
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
  for_each = { for key, map in local.json : key => map.subnets }

  vpc_id     = each.key
  cidr_block = each.value
}
```

Terraform console output :

```
> { for key, map in local.json : key => map.subnets }
{
  "vpc1" = [
    {
      "cidr" = "192.168.1.0/24"
      "name" = "subnet-one"
    },
    {
      "cidr" = "192.168.4.0/24"
      "name" = "subnet-two"
    },
  ]
  "vpc2" = [
    {
      "cidr" = "172.16.1.0/24"
      "name" = "subnet-three"
    },
    {
      "cidr" = "172.16.7.0/24"
      "name" = "subnet-four"
    },
  ]
}
```

## Error message

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 15, in resource "aws_subnet" "main":
│   15:   cidr_block = each.value
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "cidr_block": string required.
```

**[Followed this documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each)**

**@Cloudkollektiv [Thanks for the instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594506/how-to-for-each-through-a-listobjects-in-terraform-0-12/67871267#67871267)**

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? What is your expected outcome?

Comment: Well if you look at the output you cant directly access the subnets cidr because it has a "VPC1" and "VPC2" above it (you have to acess them first) and they're just a value without a key so its not possible

Comment: Please provide the output you expect to get.

Comment: So i tried mapping with `[ for key, map in local.json : {name = key, subnets = map.subnets }]` and it returns an error saying `The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.`

Comment: Can you just edit the question with the expected output?

Comment: @Marcin apologies, its there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **flatten** your json structure. For example:

```
locals {  
  json_flat = merge([
    for vpc in local.json: {
      for subnet in vpc.subnets:
      "${vpc.name}-${subnet.name}" => {
        vpc_name = vpc.name
        vpc_cidr = vpc.cidr
        subnet_name = subnet.name
        subnet_cidr = subnet.cidr
      }
    }
  ]...) 
}
```

then

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  for_each = { for index, vm in local.json : vm.name => vm }

  cidr_block = each.value.cidr

  tags = {
    Name = each.value.name
  }
}



resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
  for_each = local.json_flat

  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main[each.value.vpc_name].id
  cidr_block = each.value.subnet_cidr
}
```

Comment: `while calling merge(maps...)
local.json is object with 2 attributes
Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got "tuple".`

Comment: @Elazar Its not possibile to get such an error. I actually took your code, run it, tested my answer and I know it works. This means that your code in the question is different then your actual code.

Comment: terraform version is 1.3.5 on `provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.44.0` I just replaced the code you pasted with mine

Comment: @Elazar You have to double check what you posted in the question, especially `local.json` and what you are really using. I assure that if you take `local.json` from the question, it will work.

Comment: Wait I deleted the ... at the local file, could you please explain whats the importance of it? It did work btw

Comment: @Elazar I see. Dots are important. They change `merge([a,b,c]...)` into `merge(a,b,c)`. it is called argument expansion.

Comment: I appreicate your example, ill know how to do this next time! :)