# How to use for_each with list of objects

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create azure key vault access policies to multiple users. I have tried the following way. But I'm getting an error.

This is how my `vars.tf` looks like

```
variable "mycustomvar" {
  type = list(object({
    description        = string
    object_id          = string
    permissions        = list(string)
  }))
  default = [
    {
       description        = "One"
       object_id          = "abc123"
       secret_permissions = ["Get", "List"]
    },
    {
       description        = "Two"
       object_id          = "def345"
       secret_permissions = ["Get"]
    }
  ]
}
```

And my `resource.tf`

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "policy" {
  key_vault_id        = azurerm_key_vault.test.id
  tenant_id           = "123"
   
  for_each            = var.mycustomvar
    
  object_id           = each.value
  secret_permissions  = each.value
}
```

And getting the below error.

> The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type list of object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to for\_each through a list(objects) in Terraform 0.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594506/how-to-for-each-through-a-listobjects-in-terraform-0-12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I think this is a duplicate, the way you can achieve this is:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "policy" {
  for_each            = {for i in var.mycustomvar: i.object_id => i}
  key_vault_id        = azurerm_key_vault.test.id
  tenant_id           = "123"
  object_id           = each.value.object_id
  secret_permissions  = each.value.secret_permissions
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting explicitly that this solution relies on the `description` attributes having unique values across all of the objects. That is true in the example, but I'm accustomed to "description" meaning a human-readable description rather than a machine-oriented unique identifier. Perhaps the `object_id` attribute would make a better unique identifier, but that's of course up to the author to decide.

Comment: @MartinAtkins I always value your answers and suggestions, so I will update the answer accordingly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I used **for_each** with **set** instead of **list** before.
I think when u update like that, it may work:

```
variable "mycustomvar" {
  type = set(object({
    description        = string
    object_id          = string
    permissions        = list(string)
  }))
  default = [
    {
      description        = "One"
      object_id          = "abc123"
      secret_permissions = ["Get", "List"]
    },
    {
      description        = "Two"
      object_id          = "def345"
      secret_permissions = ["Get"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Mind the tag(s): this is a question related to Azure, your answer is for AWS.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues:

1. As @Omer pointed out, you must convert your variable to set before it can be used in a `for_each`
2. You are referring to `each.value`, when each value is an object.  You most likely want `object_id = each.value.object_id` and `secret_permissions = each.value.secret_permissions`

Comment: It is not necessary to convert the variable to be a set.