# terraform for_each not working with flatten data

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to iterate through some flattened data with a for_each. The output I get looks correct but I am missing something when iterating through it. See below:

terraform:

```
## LOCALS ##
locals {
  alternate_contacts = {
    contacts = {
      title         = "yes"
      contact_type  = ["BILLING", "OPERATIONS", "SECURITY"]
      aws_account   = ["12345", "67891", "11213"]
      email_address = ["bills@example.com", "ops@example.com", "sec@example.com"]
      name          = ["bills", "ops", "sec"]
      phone_number  = "123456789"
    }
  }

  all_aws_accounts = flatten([
    for key, contacts in local.alternate_contacts : [
      for acc_id in contacts.aws_account : {
        contacts = contacts
        acc_id   = acc_id
      }
    ]
  ])

  accounts = { for v in local.all_aws_accounts : "${v.acc_id}" => v }
}

## RESOURCE ##

resource "aws_account_alternate_contact" "alternate_contacts" {
  for_each = local.accounts

  alternate_contact_type = each.value.contacts.contact_type

  name          = each.value.contacts.name
  title         = each.value.contacts.title
  email_address = each.value.contacts.email_address
  phone_number  = each.value.contacts.phone_number
  account_id    = each.key
}
```

output:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + all_aws_accounts = {
      + "11213" = {
          + acc_id   = "11213"
          + contacts = {
              + aws_account   = [
                  + "12345",
                  + "67891",
                  + "11213",
                ]
              + contact_type  = [
                  + "BILLING",
                  + "OPERATIONS",
                  + "SECURITY",
                ]
              + email_address = [
                  + "bills@example.com",
                  + "ops@example.com",
                  + "sec@example.com",
                ]
              + name          = [
                  + "bills",
                  + "ops",
                  + "sec",
                ]
              + phone_number  = "123456789"
              + title         = "yes"
            }
        }
      + "12345" = {
          + acc_id   = "12345"
          + contacts = {
              + aws_account   = [
                  + "12345",
                  + "67891",
                  + "11213",
                ]
              + contact_type  = [
                  + "BILLING",
                  + "OPERATIONS",
                  + "SECURITY",
                ]
              + email_address = [
                  + "bills@example.com",
                  + "ops@example.com",
                  + "sec@example.com",
                ]
              + name          = [
                  + "bills",
                  + "ops",
                  + "sec",
                ]
              + phone_number  = "123456789"
              + title         = "yes"
            }
        }
      + "67891" = {
          + acc_id   = "67891"
          + contacts = {
              + aws_account   = [
                  + "12345",
                  + "67891",
                  + "11213",
                ]
              + contact_type  = [
                  + "BILLING",
                  + "OPERATIONS",
                  + "SECURITY",
                ]
              + email_address = [
                  + "bills@example.com",
                  + "ops@example.com",
                  + "sec@example.com",
                ]
              + name          = [
                  + "bills",
                  + "ops",
                  + "sec",
                ]
              + phone_number  = "123456789"
              + title         = "yes"
            }
        }
    }
```

error:

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 94, in resource "aws_account_alternate_contact" "alternate_contacts":
│   94:   alternate_contact_type = each.value.contacts.contact_type
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.contacts.contact_type is tuple with 3 elements
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "alternate_contact_type": string required.
```

I've had a look at this explanation for iterations:
[How to for_each through a list(objects) in Terraform 0.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594506/how-to-for-each-through-a-listobjects-in-terraform-0-12)
but just can't seem to get it right.

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: `The output I get looks correct` How is that correct?  ... the contact_type,  email_address & name are all lists, that is not a correct, those are all  Inappropriate value for attributes in the aws_account_alternate_contact ... https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/account_alternate_contact

Answer (score 1):

That output to me does not look correct all those are inappropriate values for attributes,
if we look at the documentation:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/account_alternate_contact

not sure why you have that structure in `alternate_contacts` to begin with...
but I'm going to assume that the 3 elements in those list are supposed to treated as a CSV, if that is that case, the code will look very different, there is no need for flattening.

```hcl
locals {
  alternate_contacts = {
    contacts = {
      title         = "yes"
      contact_type  = ["BILLING", "OPERATIONS", "SECURITY"]
      aws_account   = ["12345", "67891", "11213"]
      email_address = ["bills@example.com", "ops@example.com", "sec@example.com"]
      name          = ["bills", "ops", "sec"]
      phone_number  = "123456789"
    }
  }

  accounts = {
    for k, v in local.alternate_contacts.contacts.aws_account : v => {
      aws_account  = v
      title        = local.alternate_contacts.contacts.title
      phone_number = local.alternate_contacts.contacts.phone_number
      contact_type  = local.alternate_contacts.contacts.contact_type[k]
      email_address = local.alternate_contacts.contacts.email_address[k]
      name          = local.alternate_contacts.contacts.name[k]
    }
  }
}

output "accounts" {
  value = local.accounts
}
```

If we do a terraform plan on that, we get:

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + accounts = {
      + "11213" = {
          + aws_account   = "11213"
          + contact_type  = "SECURITY"
          + email_address = "sec@example.com"
          + name          = "sec"
          + phone_number  = "123456789"
          + title         = "yes"
        }
      + "12345" = {
          + aws_account   = "12345"
          + contact_type  = "BILLING"
          + email_address = "bills@example.com"
          + name          = "bills"
          + phone_number  = "123456789"
          + title         = "yes"
        }
      + "67891" = {
          + aws_account   = "67891"
          + contact_type  = "OPERATIONS"
          + email_address = "ops@example.com"
          + name          = "ops"
          + phone_number  = "123456789"
          + title         = "yes"
```

Comment: this is much cleaner, I'll play with this to get my desired outcome. I said the output looks correct because what I'm trying to do is get SECURITY, BILLING and OPERATIONS for each account with their respective details. E.g account `11213` would have an object for those 3 contact types with the correct `email_address` and `name`. Thanks